# Symfony calls the PHP garbage collector on Ubuntu 14.04 even when session.gc_probability is set to 0

Tags: php, symfony, garbage-collection, symfony-2.5

As the title state for some reason my Symfony 2.5 Application is calling the php garbage collector even when all of my php.ini files have:

```
session.gc_probability = 0
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Error message im getting:

```
Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5)
failed: Permission denied (13) in /<path-to-my-site>/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 432
```

FROM PHPINFO():

```
Directive               Local Value   Master Value
session.gc_divisor      1000          1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  86400         86400
session.gc_probability  0             0
```

I know that i can just give the www-data user permission to the `/var/lib/php5` folder or change the `session.save_path` to somewhere that the `www-data` user has access to already but i want to know why this process is even getting called when it should be disabled.

Comment: did you run php_ini() to see if that setting actually took hold, or was overridden later with a `ini_set()` or a `.htaccess` php_value?

Comment: According to phpinfo() it is 0, i cant find any ini_set() with it or any htaccess files that are overwriting it.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your suggestion it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found it, I guess the latest version of symfony is overwriting this by default when using the `app_dev.php`. The Symfony FrameworkBundle is setting the `session.gc_probability = 1`.

### As of Symfony 3

However, some operating systems do their own session handling and set the session.gc_probability variable to 0 to stop PHP doing garbage collection. That's why Symfony now overwrites this value to 1.

If you wish to use the original value set in your php.ini, add the following configuration:

```
# config.yml
framework:
    session:
        gc_probability: null
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection

### Previous 2.x versions

To change this add the following to your `config.yml`

```
framework:
    session:
        gc_probability: 0
```

Then clear the dev cache

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

This is where it shows the `gc_probability` defaulted to `1`. Why they dont just read from the php.ini settings im not sure.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/configuration/framework.html#gc-probability

Comment: Thankyou!
I was tryhing to determine why my garbage collection was throwing this notice:  
`Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5/sessions) failed: Permission denied (13)`
Your solution fixed it up great.

Comment: Thank you! I put it in my `config_dev.yml` to keep it permanently there for my dev server. On live it doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can set path for sessions manually. See [Symfony doc on sessions directory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/sessions_directory.html).

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'
```