# Symfony permission denied

Tags: linux, symfony, ubuntu, permissions

Can anyone help me fix the below error message I'm getting? I've finally got Symfony installed on a VM and it seems to be working ok except for the fact that I'm getting occasional messages for things like this:

```
[1/2] ContextErrorException: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_d8qgvn11jdu8rfuo1f0njokc67, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

From what I've picked up from reading around, I'm thinking it's because I have a mismatch between the owner/permissions between linux and the webserver but I don't know how this would happen (I'm just taking this as fact and I don't really understand how/why to prevent making the same mistakes in the future).

Each time I've been getting one of these errors I'm submitting a mix of the below commands to try and fix the problem but I'm guessing it's not the right way to go about it (text in brackets is my understanding/guessing of what they do):

`sudo chmod a+x <path>` 
Modifies the permissions of the directory

`sudo chmod -R 775 <path>` 
Similar to previous except that it SETS the permissions `-R` applies it recursively

`sudo chown -R <usr>:www-data <path>`
Changes the owner/group of the directory/file

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html on "Setting up Permissions" section. It talks about app/logs and app/cache, but you can do the same on any other folder you need

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony3, I had this error after installing symfony in a new fresh VPS, I resolved it using the already noted : chmod -R 775  for the LOG and CACHE but now for the SESSIONS folder.

```
chmod -R 775 var/sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar symfony permissions issue this worked for me:

`sudo chown <yourcliusername> /var/lib/php5`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33991320/1438029

Comment: Worked with the recursive option in php7:

`sudo chown -R <yourcliusername> /var/lib/php`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39346877/4276533

> You can set path for sessions manually. See [Symfony doc on sessions  directory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/sessions_directory.html).
>
> ```
> # app/config/config.yml
> framework:
>     session:
>         handler_id: session.handler.native_file
>         save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @cartant. I'm not used to contribute to stackoverflow yet. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: No, the comment was generated as part of a review. Your answer is still here, so other reviewers must have thought it was okay. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: Thanks @cartant :)