# symfony Warning: SessionHandler::read(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/...): open failed Permission denied

Tags: php, symfony, permissions

Installed Symfony.  Ran `php app/console server:run`.  At `localhost:8000` I get the following error:  `symfony Warning: SessionHandler::read(x/y/z): open failed Permission denied`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367388/symfony-permission-denied) just points to the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) which I tried unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

After reinstallation of XAMPP on my machine Symfony started to give me these errors.

I moved XAMPP from C:/XAMPP to C:/Program Files/XAMPP. This caused the Permission Denied feedback.

Simply running my XAMPP as administrator fixed the error for me

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked:

`sudo chown -R myusername x/y/z`

Is there a better solution?

---

Note: use `whoami` (deprecated) or `id` to get your username.

```
$ whoami
myusername
```

Comment: server:run is using the internal webserver of php. If you run that command, php is run with the same user. So that user needs read/write permissions on that folder. So your solution is correct..