# Symfony2 (2.6.3), garbage collector and sessions

Tags: php, symfony, session, garbage-collection

I'm having a issue, just in Debian based distros, since at CentOS 6.6 it does not happen, and I don't know how to get rid of this other than set the property `gc_probability` to `0` which leads me to another issue. This is how my configuration looks at `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        cookie_lifetime: 86400
        gc_maxlifetime: 600 # session will expire after 10 minutes of inactivity  
        gc_probability: 1
        gc_divisor: 1
```

That configuration in CentOS works perfectly as I said before but in Debian it fails with the following error:

> Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied (13)

Why? What is the cause of this?

Doing a research I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454675/symfony-calls-the-php-garbage-collector-on-ubuntu-14-04-even-when-session-gc-pro) that disabling the value will makes the error goes out but then if I disabled that one the session never expires and the page could be opened for hours (I leave it open a complete night and the day after when I hit F5 surprise the same session with same values still open which is a security hole)

Any advice around this? Solutions? Clues?

Comment: No permissions for the webserver(?) user to /var/lib/php5, this is obvious. open_basedir active or using fastcgi?

Comment: @Paziツ why the webserver should have access to `/var/lib/php5`? Anyway that directory doesn't exists under CentOS, where is it? `open_basedir` is commented (; semicolon) in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`  so I think is off, and not, not using `fastcgi`

Comment: The `session.save_path` is by default `/var/lib/php5` in debian based distros.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454675/symfony-calls-the-php-garbage-collector-on-ubuntu-14-04-even-when-session-gc-pro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony calls the PHP garbage collector on Ubuntu 14.04 even when session.gc\_probability is set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454675/symfony-calls-the-php-garbage-collector-on-ubuntu-14-04-even-when-session-gc-pro)